# how to find center of the circle from point cloud

Tags: point-clouds

Hi I am trying to find the center of the circle from point cloud. any ideas ?
Thanks
Btw I have structured light camera as well, I can get better point cloud data. This image just a example.
[circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygoqT.png)